# xargs process string as multiple arguments

Tags: gnu, xargs

Linux GNU xargs

I have the file doit with

```
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

I want to perform

```
command arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4
command arg2 arg2 arg3 arg4
```

What I can't figure out is how to do this with xargs

If one does `xargs -a doit -I % command %`

It runs

```
command 'arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4'
```

i.e run command with the first argument = 'arg1 arg2 ....'

Comment: I think you are using the wrong tool.  `xargs` is meant to gather an unknown amount of arguments from `STDIN` or a file, and run a command an unknown amount of times.  You know exactly how many arguments you have and how many times to run your command.

Comment: @KevinPanko not quite correct. I ran into this use-case, where I know I have N number of lines, each containing 2 args. So I want to be able to expand string into multiple args (by space, using regular bash semantics) _before_ passing it into cmd. xargs doesn't seem to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you use GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel -a doit eval command
```

or:

```
parallel -a doit --colsep ' ' command
```

To learn more: Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1 and walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). You command line
with love you for it.